# Using srun to access memory of nodes in slurm cluster

Tags: ssh, slurm, hpc

I am currently moving from one HPC to another, and am encountering a small problem:

The calculations are writing a lot of material on disc, and in order to prevent the process from overwhelming the file system, we are running it in the /dev/shm local memory of the nodes, and only transfer the final results.

So far, what we did was simply prepare the files to be executed (loop_i_j_C_num), then ssh into the individual nodes, and run them. However, the new cluster does not allow ssh, and the only way I have found to access the individual nodes is srun with the overlap option:

```
export TMP_DIR=/dev/shm/CALC_${i}_${j}_${C_num} #the directory in the local memory to run the Code
srun --overlap --pty --jobid=$SLURM_JOB_ID -w $Node_name $SHELL << EOT #srun into the node
mkdir  ${TMP_DIR} #prepare the directory
mv ${CALC_DIR}/loop_${i}_${j}_${C_num}.sh ${TMP_DIR} #move the exectuable
cd ${TMP_DIR} #move into the directory
chmod +x ${TMP_DIR}/loop_${i}_${j}_${C_num}.sh #make sure the execution permission is set
${TMP_DIR}/loop_${i}_${j}_${C_num}.sh & #start the executable in the background and leave
exit
EOT
```

However, I am getting a number of errors, and the executables aren't started:

```
srun: error: ioctl(TIOCGWINSZ): Inappropriate ioctl for device
srun: error: Not using a pseudo-terminal, disregarding --pty option
```

If anyone knows what is going wrong, or knows a better way of doing this then to abuse srun for this, I would be happy either way.